# 'MemorySize' value failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 3008

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, computer-science

Whenever i try to increase the memory above 3008 MB of my lambda function, i get the error: `'MemorySize' value failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 3008`. Although it says i can Set the memory between 128 MB and 10240 MB, and i am in a supported region for setting the memory above 3008MB (us-east-1 - [AWS Lambda now supports up to 10 GB of memory and 6 vCPU cores for Lambda Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/)), its still giving me the error, i'm honestly stuck because i keep getting this error: `Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed`
which requires more memory, but i cant set it higher than 3008 MB. This is a screenshot of the error i'm getting:
[image: Erorr]

Answer (score 3):

Is it with a new AWS account? If it is I imagine you're hitting a constraint for new accounts. A quick message to support to let them know will probably fit it.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response, i will message support and see what they can do, and yes this is a fairly new account, i have had it for about 5 months